# Find the count of subarrays whose sum is equal to given value

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to understand a program where the task is to find how many sub arrays are possible whose sum is equal to given value.

Here is the working code with O(N) complexity taken from [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-subarrays-sum-exactly-equal-k/):

```
static int findSubarraySum(int arr[], int K) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> prevSum = new HashMap<>();
    int res = 0;
    int currsum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        currsum += arr[i];
        if (currsum == K)
            res++;
        if (prevSum.containsKey(currsum - K))
            res += prevSum.get(currsum - K);
        Integer count = prevSum.get(currsum);
        if (count == null)
            prevSum.put(currsum, 1);
        else
            prevSum.put(currsum, count + 1);
    }

    return res;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] = {10, 2, -2, -20, 10};
    int sum = -10;
    int n = arr.length;
    System.out.println(findSubarraySum(arr, sum));
}
```

I am not able to understand the logic behind below code:

```
            if (prevSum.containsKey(currsum - K))   
                res += prevSum.get(currsum - K);
```

How the HashMap in above code is helpful in getting correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prevSum[i]` contains the number of contiguous subarrays starting with the first element that sum to `i`. E.g., for the array `3, 4, 2, -4, 2`, the entries would look as follows:

```
prevSum[3] = 1  // { { 3 } }
prevSum[5] = 1  // { { 3, 4, 2, -4 } }
prevSum[7] = 2  // { { 3, 4 }, { 3, 4, 2, -4, 2} }
prevSum[9] = 1  // { { 3, 4, 2 } }
```

If you have a current prefix sum `currsum` of `10` and you are looking for subarrays that sum to `K=3`, you want to remove subarrays that start with the first element and sum to `7` to get an appropriate subarray that sums to `3`. Example:

```
3, 4, 2, -4, 2, 1, 2, -5, 2
                   ^
|------------------|
              currsum = 10

|--|  -> sums to 7
     |-------------| -> sums to 3

|------------| -> sums to 7
                |--| -> sums to 3
```

Hence, at this location, you have found two possible subarrays that sum to `K`. Therefore, `res += prevSum.get(currsum - K)`.